# gmaps4rails isn't displaying given coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have gotten the entire map to display correctly with no issues.  However, the map always loads at coordinates of `0,0`.  I know I'm passing the longitude and latitude correctly as well.

Here's the printed json which the `gmaps4rails` method receives:

`[{"lat":40.7142,"lng":74.0064}]`

Below is also the code used in various areas of production...

**VIEW**

```
<%= @maps %>
<%= gmaps4rails(@maps) %>
```

**MODEL**

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false, :lat => :lat, :lng => :lng

def lat
  40.7142
end

def lng
  74.0064
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

`@maps = Event.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails`

I've decided as you'll see in my model to explicitly pass a latitude and longitude.  I do have my database setup with columns `latitude` and `longitude`, however, I'm working with test data at the moment and cannot expect a reliable result.  Until then, I'll use the coordinates for New York City, NY.

Here's the outputted Javascript:

```
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":40.7142,"lng":74.0064}];
Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
 window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
```

I do get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Gmaps4RailsGoogle> has no method create_markers`.

Also, here is a picture of the issue (notice the printed json above the map as done in the view code above):

[image: A lovely little description!]

Comment: I don't know rails or gmap4rails... what does the generated javascript look like?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Can you list all the javascript files that are loaded in your view - just to confirm all the gmap4rails JS files are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using Coffeescript.  Before I had manually copied the javascript files because I didn't want to use Coffeescript on my application.

My installation was wrong, use Coffeescript.